# Error C2050 switch expression not integral

Tags: c, switch-statement

So I'm wrestling with this particular snippet of code:

```
    scanf("%f", &x, &y);
    scanf("%c", &operator);

    switch (x)
    {
    case ('p') : x = lastNum;
        break;

    case ('q') : return(0);

    default: break;
```

And Visual Studio is throwing up Error 2050 as a result of it. Now, I understand why it's happening, since x in this case is a float and I'm trying to account for non-numerical input, but is there any way to fix this without resorting to some form of wizardry?

**Edit**

This is the entirety of my code, still broken but I think my snippet was kind of useless.

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
float x, y, lastNum;
char operator;

while (1)
{
    scanf("%f %c %f", &x, &operator, &y);

    switch (operator)
    {
    case('+') : lastNum = x + y;
        printf("\nANS = ", "%f", x + y);
        break;

    case('-') : lastNum = x - y;
        printf("\nANS = ", "%f", x - y);

        break;

    case('*') : lastNum = x * y;
        printf("\nANS = ", "%f", x * y);

        break;

    case('/') : lastNum = x / y;
        printf("\nANS = ", "%f", x / y);

        break;

    }


}



}
```

Comment: `switch ((int)x)` too much wizardry?

Comment: The code doesn't really make sense. Not only because of the float in the switch but then you have `char` values in the `case`. That is, comparing `float` (or some derivative) with `char`. What is the intention?

Comment: What *floating point value* do you expect to equal `'p'` or `'q'`?

Comment: @Absoguar: "I'm trying to account for non-numerical input"... There's no such thing as "non-numerical input" for `%f` format specifier in `scanf`. `scanf` will simply refuse to read your input if you enter something non-numerical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on your comments to another answer, I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish - the user has the option to enter floating point values *or* non-numeric values such as `'p'` (to use a previous value) and `'q'` (to quit), and you're trying to figure out how to account for both.

Using `scanf( "%f", &x );` won't work, as it won't accept `'p'` and `'q'` as valid inputs; it will return a 0 for the matching failure, and `x` won't be updated.

Instead, you're going to have to read the input as text, test to see if the first character is either `'p'`, `'q'`, or a digit, and then process from there.  Assuming I've understood your intentions correctly, you'd want to do something like the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for strtod

char input[SIZE]; // where SIZE is large enough to account for your largest
                  // possible floating point input, plus an optional sign,
                  // plus a newline, plus the 0 terminator.

/**
 * Read input as text
 */
if ( fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) ) 
{
  /**
   * Check for a newline character - if it isn't present, then the user
   * typed in a longer input than we're capable of handling.
   */
  char *newline = strchr( input, '\n' );
  if ( !newline )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "input too long, try again\n" );
    return 0;
  }

  /**
   * Remove the trailing newline
   */
  *newline = 0;

  /**
   * Skip over any leading whitespace
   */
  char *p = input;
  while ( isspace( *p ) ) 
    p++;                    

  /**
   * If the first non-whitespace is a digit or a sign, process as 
   * a numeric input
   */ 
  if ( isdigit( *p ) || *p == '+' || *p == '-' )
  {
    /**
     * Convert input to a floating point value, save to x
     */
    char *chk;
    x = (float) strtod( p, &chk ); // I'm assuming x is declared float

    /**
     * Make sure there wasn't any garbage at the end of the floating-point
     * input.
     */
    if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
    {
      fprintf( "%s is not a valid floating-point input\n", p );
      return 0;
    }
  }
  else if ( tolower(*p) == 'p' )
  {
    x = lastVal;
  }
  else if ( tolower(*p) == 'q' )
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Don't know what to do with %s\n", p );
    return 0;
  }
}
/**
 * process x
 */
```

**Edit**

If you're not allowed to use routines from stdlib.h, then the first thing you should do is slap your teacher for making this assignment harder than it needs to be.

Well, maybe not - that might affect your grade.

You can use `sscanf` instead of `strtod` to do the conversion, but the error checking is a bit less straightforward:

```
if ( isdigit( *p ) || *p == '+' || *p == '-' )
{
  char chk;
  int r = sscanf( p, "%f%c", &x, &chk );
  if ( r < 1 || ( r == 2 && !isspace( chk ) && chk != 0 ) )
  {
    // bad input, handle like above
  }
}
```

All of the `*scanf` functions will return the number of successful conversions and assignments.  Under normal circumstances, we expect to read 2 items - the floating point number and the trailing newline character.  If we read 2 items and `chk` is *not* a newline or a 0, then we had trailing bad input after the floating point number.  If we read less than one item, then we either had a matching failure (input wasn't a valid float) or had an error during the read.  Since we already checked for a leading digit before getting this far, we *shouldn't* get a total matching failure at this point, but I'm including the check for completeness' sake.

**Edit of the Edit**

Well, you're definitely not going to want to just paste all that into your code for a number of reasons.  I was mainly trying to show fairly robust ways of checking your input when it can take one of several forms.

The main thing to take away from all of this is the following:

1. If the first thing on your input line can be either text or a numeric value, read and store it as a text string first.  You can use `fgets()` (which will read *everything* up to the newline, or until you've filled your target buffer, whichever comes first), or `scanf( "%s", ... )` (which will read up to the next whitespace character);
2. Check the first non-whitespace character of your input - if it's a sign or a digit, then you'll need to convert that input into a floating-point value.
3. Read your operator and second floating point input.

Here's yet another method that's a bit less robust (this will replace the `scanf( "%f %c %f", &x, &operator, &y );` in your updated code snippet above):

```
char xstr[SIZE]; // large enough to hold a single floating-point value as
                 // text, plus sign, plus terminator

/**
 * Read the first input up to the next whitespace character
 */
scanf( "%s", xstr );
if ( xstr[0] == 'p' )
{
  x = lastVal;
}
else if ( xstr[0] == 'q' )
{
  return 0;
}
else
{
 /**
  * Convert x to a float value
  */
 sscanf( xstr, "%f", &x );

 /**
  * Read the remainder of the input
  */
 scanf( " %c %f", &operator, &y );
}
```

and then switch on operator (this assumes your input can take the form of `12.3 + 4.56` *and* `p + 7.89`).  This is guaranteed not to use anything that isn't in `stdio.h`.

I realized that using `fgets` will read in the *entire* line of input, including your operator and second operand, so I changed the above to read just the first input.

You *should* check the return value of `scanf` (and `sscanf`) to make sure you actually read what you meant to before processing; I left it out of the above to make the code a little clearer.

The one thing I want to you to take away from this is that interactive I/O in C is a *pain in the ass*.

Comment: Oh yeah, we're not allowed to use stdlib.h, our automatic marking system is very...Awkward about anything that isn't stdio.h

Comment: I don't think I'm qualified enough to follow your code. How would I go about incorporating into my mess? I appreciate if you don't want to answer this directly but I value any tips.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I've been getting along with C fairly well until Interactive I/O so this is just another day on the battlefield for me. I'll need to hammer how fgets and the rest of these functions work because our professors don't seem keen on covering them. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can not have char in case when you are storing float value in your variable x.
If you want to store char value in x then change the scanf statement to this
    scanf(%c,&x)
otherwise you store float value in x and in CASE statement you write float value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your code,

```
 scanf("%f", &x, &y);
```

does not make any sense, as you're giving one format specifier and passing two arguments.

That said, regarding the error message, quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.8.4.2

> The controlling expression of a `switch` statement shall have integer type.

so, you cannot use a `float` value as the controlling expression of the `switch` statement. However, from your following code snippet, we can see, you're using `int` value as the `case` statement, so you can surely make the controlling element as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make x as a char or int variable. You can't use a float number in a switch and compare to a char. Also, you should have:

```
scanf("%c %f", &x, &y);
```

Since you are receiving two values there.

You could use a different variable in this case instead of x:

```
case ('p') : x = lastNum;
```

If you want to save a number... Instead of using x for receiving this lastNum, you could create a different variable and use x only for the cases.

Comment: The thing is I kind of need to keep x as a float because if the user enters p or q instead of a number for x then two different things need to happen. If the user enters a number then a calculation needs to take place.

Comment: @Absoguar: `scanf( "%f", &x )` will *never* read a non-numeric input into `x`; if the input isn't a valid float, *nothing gets written to `x`* and the bad input is left in the input stream to foul up the next input operation.

Comment: Then, you should use a different variable for your switch or use a different approach. What are the conditions for your program to enter case('p') or case('q')? It's not clear in your code...

Comment: @JohnBode Gotcha, that explains why that part of my code didn't work. In that case could you suggest how I could make it work? We've pretty much been told we need to use just that one variable for this. If I make variable y a char as well could I hypothetically perform a calculation on the two chars?

Comment: @JessicaCarneiro Should I just post my whole code in here? It's not terribly long but I wanted to refrain from posting all of it since I'm trying to avoid being accused of asking for homework help.